# Twitter Bootstrap centering responsive navbar gap on background hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried this solution in order to center my bootstrap nav , however is its causing a small gap at the bottom of my on hover effects? I think this is due to the float but i dont know how to fix it.

```
navbar-collapse.collapse {
text-align: center; /* Set this */
height: auto !important;
padding-bottom: 0;
overflow: visible !important;
font-weight:bold;
}

/* This should be around line 4866 in your bootstrap.css */
.navbar-nav {
display:inline-block;
float: none;
margin: 0;
}`
```

EDIT ----

Link to code http://www.bootply.com/sp1jl3CnJ0

Comment: post your html as well

Comment: fiddle or codepen demo would be helpfull

Comment: If you problem has to do with floats not clearing properly, use `clear:both` to clear your floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [this](http://www.bootply.com/AGpbibsTON)

CSS

```
.navbar-nav {
    display: table;
     float: none;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: That seems to work , thanks. Could you explain how its doing things differently?

Comment: If you remove the float for child li and apply inline-block to it will also work. I am not sure what exactly was going wrong with inline-block for ul. May be because for child li having float was creating problem to it.

Comment: Could you show me how to do that if its not too much trouble?